# Elixir - plug is being triggered in other actions in Phoenix controller

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, plug

I'm using `PolicyWonk` for authorization and I created this policy:

```
def policy(
    %{current_user: current_user, organisation: organisation} = _assigns,
    :organisation_view
  )
    when not is_nil(current_user) and not is_nil(organisation) do
  case current_user.organisation_id == organisation.organisation_id do
    true -> :ok
    _value -> {:error, :forbidden}
  end
end

def policy(_assigns, :organisation_view), do: {:error, :forbidden}
```

My controller is defined like this:

```
defmodule MyAppWeb.OrganisationController do
  plug(MyAppWeb.Policies, :organisation_view when action in [:show])

  def create(conn, %{"organisation" => organisation_params}) do
    with {:ok, %Organisation{} = organisation} <- Accounts.create_organisation(organisation_params) do
      conn
      |> put_status(:created)
      |> put_resp_header("location", Routes.organisation_path(conn, :show, organisation))
      |> render("show.json", organisation: organisation)
    end
  end

  def show(conn, %{"id" => id}) do
    with {:ok, organisation} <- Accounts.find_organisation(%{"id" => id}) do
      render(conn, "show.json", organisation: organisation)
    end
  end
end
```

I noticed that attempting to create an organisation fails and throws the `{:error, :forbidden}` tuple. The policy is only meant to affect `:show` as per my guard clause, but why is it affecting `:create` as well?

Comment: It seems the organisation gets indeed created, but in the last line of `create/2` you do call `show`, which is apparently responding with `forbidden`.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin So, `render(conn, "show.json", organisation: organisation)` is the same as `redirect(conn, to: organisation_path(conn, :show, organisation))`?

Comment: No, it’s not the same. `redirect/2` sends `HTTP 302` response to the client, `render/2` renders the template inplace. Why?